# Setting WPF Delay from code in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am working on WPF application (.NET 4.5), and using `Caliburn.Micro`. I am generating a list of questions and answers in  `ListBox` answers can be of 3 types (RadioButtons, DropDowns and Textboxes). When question is being answered, property triggers change in ViewModel and next question is being added.
Problem I ran into is when symbol is being added to `Textbox` it immediately fires property change.

```
public string TextValue
    {
        get { return _textValue; }
        set
        {
            _textValue = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TextValue);
        }
    }
```

Normally (for non dynamically generated controls) I could delay it by using 'new'

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue, Delay=500}"/>`

but since I am generating these questions I am not sure on how to proceed with this.

**Is there a way to set `Delay` to generated control from code behind?**

**UPDATE:**
this is how XAML looks like. List is being populated with questions on runtime (from DB), and questions do change based on previous answers, so there is no way of setting anything in XAML.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Corp.Conveyancing.Desktop.Views.Probate.PifWFlowQuestionsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:probate="clr-namespace:Corp.Conveyancing.Desktop.Views.Probate"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Grid Margin="10" Width="600" Height="400" >
        <ListBox x:Name="QuestionItems" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="true" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="380" Width="580" probate:ListBoxExtenders.AutoScrollToEnd="True" >
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle >
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UPDATE2:**
I have `BindableCollection<QuestionItemViewModel>` which is property in `PifWFlowQuestionsViewModel` to which I am adding only first question and then based on answer I am adding more questions,a nd based on those adding more and so on.

```
public class PifWFlowQuestionsViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private BindableCollection<QuestionItemViewModel> _questionItems =
        new BindableCollection<QuestionItemViewModel>();

    public BindableCollection<QuestionItemViewModel> QuestionItems
    {
        get { return _questionItems; } 
        set
        {
            _questionItems = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => QuestionItems);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you generating the items for the ListBox? Type inference and datatemplates or manually generating the controls via code-behind?

Comment: @toadflakz I have `BindableCollection<QuestionItemViewModel>` which is property in `PifWFlowQuestionsViewModel` to which I am adding only first question and then based on answer I am adding more questions,a nd based on those adding more and so on.

Comment: *Problem I ran into is when symbol is being added to Textbox it immediately fires property change*... why is that a problem?

Comment: @Sheridan adds next question after every key press, and sets focus on it.

Comment: Then you must have set some `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`... change it to `LostFocus` so that it only updates when typing is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it, might be not THE solution, but it was quick and easy.
I realize that it does not answer to the title of the question, however it does provide solution to the problem above, and I am sure someone will find this useful.

```
public class QuestionTextViewModel : QuestionItemViewModel
{
    private Timer Timer { get; set; }

    public QuestionTextViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, TransactionDetail transactionDetail)
        : base(transactionDetail)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        TransactionDetailId = transactionDetail.TransactionDetailId;
        this.Timer = new Timer(1500) {AutoReset = false};
        this.Timer.Elapsed += TextValueTimer_Elapsed;
    }

    public string TextValue
    {
        get { return _textValue; }
        set
        {
            _textValue = value;
            this.Timer.Stop();
            this.Timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void TextValueTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TextValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an `ItemTemplateSelector` on the `ListBox` and basing what type of `DataTemplate` is used for the `QuestionItemViewModel` based on the returned properties for the new item.

It would definitely be possible to do the control generation in XAML then as you're specifying the `DataTemplate` content.